# Codeigniter remove index.php on Nginx

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx

I'm using Codeigniter framework, i test the website on shared hosting and it work fine with .htaccess. but when i upload it to an other server who has Nginx, i can't remove index.php. I tried almost all googel's two first pages i had the same result none of them worked for me, i want to remove index.php from URL. this is the htaccess that worked for me.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

i want the corespond of this htaccess in nginx.config.
i don't know what's the problem.

Comment: You googled it, so what happens when you use [first](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/) result?

Comment: @Tpojka nothing. all links without index.php. but they don't work until i add index.php manuly.

Comment: Have you tried to restart nginx after changes?

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts too.

Turned out playing with this in the config.php file helped.

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

I'm using the same htaccess rules at present too

Comment: htaccess is not working on Nginx server. i already did this $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; but the problem is with Nginx

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** : go to codeigniter folder, open the file config.php and remove "index.php" from $config['index_page'] = ''

**Step 2** : Create .htaccess file in codeigniter folder and paste below code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /codeigniter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

or

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>

<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
  SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.YOUR_PROJECT_NAME)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
  Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
</ifmodule>
```

**Step 3** : find

```
      $config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"
```

and replace with

```
      $config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

also check

```
      $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

**Step 4** :restart xampp server and check ..

Answer (score 0):

**Try This For Better Solution**

```
Step 1: Remove index.php from config.php. Open 
/application/config/config.php 
and remove index.php to “” ...
Step 2: Edit htaccess file – For Apache Server. NOTE: This step is not for 
nginx server users, Please check Step 2 for Nginx. ...
Step 3: Edit nginx.conf file – For NGINX Server.
```